# Joining multiple tables by removing leading alpha character

Tags: sql

I need to match column.table1 = '1234' to column.table2 = 'B1234'. Is there a way to bypass the leading alpha character in table2? More specifically, can this be achieved by using an INNER JOIN clause?

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `substring()`. Docs and more here: https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-string-functions/sql-substring/

Answer (score 0):

You can join them via a LIKE.

An underscore `_` can match any-1 character in the LIKE syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t2.col LIKE CONCAT('_', t1.col)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON CAST(t1.column AS VARCHAR) = SUBSTRING(t2.column,2,LEN(t2.column)-1)
```

The `SUBSTRING()` function here takes the value of Table2.column starting at the second position, thus skipping the alpha character at the beginning.